# Cucumber `press button` failure (Capybara::ElementNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, bdd, capybara, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm a relative newbie starting up a new Ruby on Rails app.  I started by following a combination of instructions at https://github.com/intridea/omniauth, http://www.communityguides.eu/articles/16, http://intridea.com/2011/1/31/easy-rails-admin-login-with-google-apps-and-omniauth?blog=company .  At the point everything appeared to work correctly, I started to write my very first cucumber features and steps.  I was able to get a couple of steps up and running, but I've been bogged down on a step that I thought was built in.  I have a form with two `submit_tag`s but I can't get a scenario to successfully pass a basic `And I press "button"` step.

possibly relevant gems:

```
rails (3.1.0.rc4)
capybara (1.0.0)
cucumber (1.0.1)
cucumber-rails (1.0.2)
nokogiri (1.4.7)
gherkin (2.4.5)
rack-test (0.6.0)
selenium-webdriver (0.2.2)
```

section of the form in question:

```
<%= form_tag :controller => "services", :action => "newaccount" do %>
  <%= submit_tag "confirm", :id => "confirm", :title => "confirm", :value => "confirm", :text => "confirm", :name => "confirm" %> 
  <%= submit_tag "cancel", :id => "cancel", :title => "cancel", :value => "cancel", :text => "cancel", :name => "cancel"  %>
<% end %>
```

scenario in question:

```
Scenario: I register with a valid and currently active google account
    Given I am not registered
     When I sign in with a valid and currently active google account
      And I press "confirm"  # <-- THE PROBLEMATIC STEP
     Then I should see "Your account has been created and you have been signed in!"
```

I think this is the relevant web_step (straight from the default web_steps.rb which I have not edited at all):

```
When /^(?:|I )press "([^"]*)"$/ do |button|
  click_button(button)
end
```

relevant cucumber output:

```
Scenario: I register with a valid and currently active google account            # features/auth_and_auth/initial_tests.feature:6
  Given I am not registered                                                      # features/step_definitions/authentication_steps.rb:1
  When I sign in with a valid and currently active google account                # features/step_definitions/authentication_steps.rb:5
  And I press "confirm"                                                          # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:52
    no button with value or id or text 'confirm' found (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
    (eval):2:in `click_button'
    ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:53:in `/^(?:|I )press "([^"]*)"$/'
    features/auth_and_auth/initial_tests.feature:9:in `And I press "confirm"'
  Then I should see "Your account has been created and you have been signed in!" # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:105
```

relevant html output:

```
<input id="confirm" name="confirm" text="confirm" title="confirm" type="submit" value="confirm">
<input id="cancel" name="cancel" text="cancel" title="cancel" type="submit" value="cancel">
```

As is obvious, I've accounted for `value`, `id`, `text`, as well as `name` and `title`.  I also saw a post that said the input type had to be specified as `submit` which it appears to have been.  And I've tried it with both the `confirm` button and the `cancel` button.

After searching everywhere that I know about, and trying every suggestion that looked even remotely relevant, I'm at an impasse.  What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure cucumber is actually on the right page when the step is being called? Capybara has an incredibly useful 'save_and_open_page' method.. try putting that above the click_button call in web_steps.rb and check that it's actually on the correct page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if the code below is the best way to deal with the problem I encountered, but it is getting the relevant step to pass.

```
When /^(?:|I )press "([^"]*)"$/ do |button|
# click_button(button)  # the original web_steps.rb version that fails
  %{I press (button)}   # my revised version that passes
end
```

I'd still appreciate any feedback on:

- why the original web_steps.rb version fails,
- whether this is an appropriate approach or not, and
- if there is a more 'rails' way to deal with this.

Comment: Thanks @MacSean it worked for me too. I was searching for this solution since last 3 days.. you made my day :)